# Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 1 vs Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 2

Tags: certification

Can someone who hold this certification(*Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 1*) explain the difference between Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 1 vs Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 2 ?.

Because from the course description mentioned here

http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers

it looks like for both SCPD I & II, apex & visualforce study guide is given as study material.

The only difference between SCPD I & II is that "advanced programmatic capabilities" mentioned in the course description for II.

Is there much more granular description available ?
More specifically how deep & vast one must know of the different VF & Apex topics..
Hope I am clear..if not do let me know

Answer (score 1):

The Platform I and II developer certifications is designed to differentiate the beginners and experienced developers. The platform I exam question on apex visualforce and lightning will be very straight forward like syntax, components and vf tags Where as the questions in Platform II is of mostly code snippet based like what will be the output of above code and also the platform II covers lot of webservices questions than Platform I. To take the platform II exam you need a real time experience of atleast of 3-4 years on coding using force.com platform.

Comment: I disagree with the assessment of needing 3-4 years of experience on the force.com platform. I think 1 year of full-time experience is a good point to start thinking about taking the exam. Ultimately you need to be the judge. If you've worked with lots of different aspects of the force.com platform such as Chatter, Lightning Components, Batches, SOAP/REST API and Triggers, 1 year is plenty. If you've been constrained to building only Visualforce pages for a year, you may need to study a bunch and hold off.